# jQuery script works inline but not in external file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Many people had the same/similar issue before, unfortunately none of the previous posts helped solving my problem.

I have a simple jQuery script sliding up/down a DIV.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Standard-Template</title>

...

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../scripts/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/magnific-pleopup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/cycle/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/cycle/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/scriptlibrary.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

...

<script>

        $("section.job-section div.job-trigger").click(function() {
        if($(this).parents("section").hasClass("expanded")) {
            // einklappen
            $(this).parents("section").addClass("close");
            $("section.expanded h3.job-trigger.close").removeClass("close");
            $("section.expanded div.job-trigger").removeClass("close");
            $("section.expanded.close div.job-details").slideUp();
$(this).parents("section").removeClass("expanded").removeClass("close");
        } else {
            // ausklappen
            $(this).parents("section").addClass("expanded");
            $("section.expanded h3.job-trigger").addClass("close");
            $("section.expanded div.job-trigger").addClass("close");
            $("section.expanded div.job-details").slideDown();
        }
        });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This works fine. But, when I try to put this jQuery-script into an external file it doesn't work anymore.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/scriptlibrary.js"></script>
```

This won't work. The file scriptlibrary.js contains a couple of jQuery-scripts and it does surround all code with (document).ready(function()...

What I tried so far:

1) When using the jQuery-script inline I don't have (function)... or (document).ready(function()... and the script still works.
When I add (document).ready(function()... it won't work anymore :)

2) I also tried placing the link to the .js-files at the bottom of the webpage as many people here suggest, but the issue persists, it has no effect.

Kind regards,
Milan

Comment: as i see, you must make one onWindowLoad, becose the DOM is not loaded yet

Comment: Did you try to add a `console.log('pass')` in your newly created js file, to see if it even reads the thing?

Comment: i think you need to include the jquery.js library in your index page from the official [link](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: Are you using `$` in front of `(document).ready(function()`? What errors are thrown in browser console?

Comment: @ProgrammingGeek jquery is already there in the page, it's the first `<script>` tag.

Comment: OP are you sure your scriptlibrary.js file is definitely loading (see browser network tab to check it loads with a 200 status), and no syntax errors? And definitely all code inside it wrapped within `$(document).ready(function() { //... });`? There's basically no reason why what you're doing shouldn't work, so there's probably a little niggle somewhere like the file not loading, or a typo or something.

Comment: It would be great help if you could create a fiddle for this

Comment: One possible reason could be that the script is being loaded and executed before the DOM. In case of inline code, the code is part of the DOM. Could you please check and see if this is the case?

Comment: @me_digvijay use of a `$(document).ready(function() { //... });` wrapper (either inline or an in an external file) would mitigate against this. OP claims to be doing this already, although I think we need to see the code of the external file in order to verify it's been done correctly.